# Reverse lookup in a resource file?

Tags: c#, resource-files

Using C#, I need to do a reverse look up my resource file. I know how to grab a string value using the ResourceManager class but I now want to do the opposite. Will I need to load the resource file into an xml file first?

The reason I want to do this is because I have some hard coded enums that are in English and my resource file contains English to Spanish keys and values. So when my code is looking for WorkflowSupport.Completed enum but the workflow returns "Terminado" rather then "Completed", it will fail.

What I am specifically trying to do is:

I have a SharePoint workflow that returns the step the workflow is in. I have localized this workflow, so instead of returning "Completed" it will return "Terminado". I have an enum with five hard coded values that match the various states of the workflow (Completed, Cancelled, Reassigned, Terminated and Processing). Since the workflow returns "Terminado" instead of "Completed", the code can't match "Terminado" to any of the enum values and fails. I want to do a reverse lookup in my resource file, so if I get a value like "Terminado" I can return 
"Completed" and successfully match it to the enum member "Completed".

If there is a better way to do this, I am all ears :)

Comment: Are you comparing an enum name to a localizable string value ?

Comment: Yes, using the .ToString() method on the enum. However it will fail since the localized string will be in Spanish and the enum will be in English

Comment: But why are you doing this ? Can't you call your enum value "COMPLETED", and your resource key "COMPLETED" with 2 values: eng: "Completed", esp: "Terminado". So you can access to the resource through the key "COMPLETED" that is culture-invariant ?

Comment: Oh... I maybe got it, probably you're comparing the value in some  textbox (or something simila) to the enum value.. right ? Please specify in your question what exactly are you doing, because likely there are better ways to do this...

Comment: I could just add another entry to my resource file, one for "Completed"->"Terminado" and one for "Terminado"->"Completed" I am not grabbing any values from a text box, I am grabbing one of five values in the enum, but on one end they are in Spanish and the other end they are in English

Comment: The problem is that is normally not very good to compare an hardcoded value with a localizable value. So, rather than solve the lookup issue, you should accurately tell us what are you trying to accomplish through this comparison, because probably there are better ways :)

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience in SharePoint nor in WorkFlow foundation so I can't be of help. I suspect there must a way to return a key along with the Localized step name, if so that's a way to solve the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of comparing the string values of the enum you have to compare their values.

For example, if you are working with a Combobox, you have a text and a value (numeric value of the enum) for each item, the user selects the text and you just cast the value back to your enum type.

Are you using Forms or WPF?

Comment: The OP is using a sharepoint workflow, not a winforms control.